# Removing multiple currencies in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, admin, multicurrency, switcher

How I can remove my another currency in the admin? I have one website, one store and one view, but into frontend still has two currencies.

The cache and varnish is disabled, is in developer mode.

Comment: please clear cache proper & also varnish cache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check these:

- Go to **Stores** >> **Configuration** >> **General** >> **Currency Setup**, then check how many currencies have you selected under **Allowed Currencies**. If there are more than one currency, then first you need to deselect currency which you don't want. Then click on **Save Config** button.
- Now go to **Stores** >> **Currency Rates** and check whether there are more than one currency showing. I don't think that after above step you will be getting more than one currency here.

Note: After completing above steps, remember to flush cache from **System** >> **Cache Management**.

I hope above workaround will help you to solve your problem.